# How can I do <T super V>?

Tags: java, generics

I have a method looks like this.

```java
public static <E extends Enum<E> & FieldEnum<E, V>, V>
    void fieldValues(class<E> enumType,
                     Collection<? super V> fieldValues) {
    for ( enumConstant : enumType.getEnumConstants()) {
        fieldValues.add(enumConstant.fieldValue());
    }
}
```

It might work.

```
List<Some> list = new ArrayList<>();
fieldValues(Some.class, list);
```

Now I want to change the method to return the given collection parameter(`fieldValues`). I did this.

```java
public static <E extends Enum<E> & FieldEnum<E, V>, V, T super V>
    Collection<T> fieldValues(Class<E> enumType,
                              Collection<T> fieldValues) {
    for (E enumConstant : enumType.getEnumConstants()) {
        fieldValues.add(enumConstant.fieldValue());
    }
    return fieldValues;
}
```

And the compiler complains.

```
com/github/.../lang/FieldEnums.java:[78,61] > expected
com/github/.../lang/FieldEnums.java:[78,62] illegal start of type
com/github/.../lang/FieldEnums.java:[78,69] '(' expected
```

How can I solve this? What is a proper way to return given collection so that I can do

```
List<Some> = fieldValues(Some.class, new ArrayList<Some>());
```

?

I found I just can

```
public static <E extends Enum<E> & FieldEnum<E, V>, V>
    Collection<? super V> fieldValues(
    Class<E> enumType, Collection<? super V> fieldValues) {
    for (E enumConstant : enumType.getEnumConstants()) {
        fieldValues.add(enumConstant.fieldValue());
    }
    return fieldValues;
}
```

Is there any other way better than this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering for my own question so that anyone who has a similar problem can help themselves.

```
public static <E extends Enum<E> & FieldEnum<E, V>, V,
               T extends Collection<? super V>>
    T fieldValues(Class<E> enumType, T fieldValues) {
    for (E enumConstant : enumType.getEnumConstants()) {
        fieldValues.add(enumConstant.fieldValue());
    }
    return fieldValues;
}
```

Now I can do this.

```
List<Some> list = fieldValues(Some.class, new ArrayList<>());
```

Comment: Does that really compile, or does your method return `T` instead of `Collection<? super V>`?  You shouldn't be able to assign `Collection<>` to `List<>` without a cast, generics aside.

Comment: @MarkPeters Sorry, fixed.